# Why does groupby query create syntax error

Tags: sql, laravel

i have problem with GroupBy in Laravel. Error that is writen is:

```
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'smf.serije_epizode.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `serije_epizode` where `id_serije` = 1 group by `sezona` order by `sezona` asc)
```

Also, fields in database are:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6akE.png

And query in laravel framework is:

```
public function prikaz($id)
{
    $serija = DB::table('serije')
        ->where('id', $id)
        ->first();
    $epizode = DB::table('serije_epizode')
        ->where('id_serije', '=', $id)
        ->orderBy('sezona', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('sezona')
        ->get();
    return view('serije.prikaz', ['serija' => $serija, 'epizode' => $epizode]);
}
```

View blade:

```
     @foreach ($epizode as $serijaa)
Sezona: {{$serijaa->sezona}} | Epizoda: {{$serijaa->br_epizode}} - {{$serijaa->naziv}
  @endforeach
```

So why i just can't group by "sezona" (mean Seasons), when i have that. What am i doing wrong. Thanks. :)

Comment: every column in the select list that is not a calculated column must be declared in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this issue.

The 1st and the 'best practise' is to include you column in the select query.

```
DB::table('serije_epizode')
        ->select('id_serije')
        ->where('id_serije', '=', $id)
        ->orderBy('sezona', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('sezona')
        ->get();
```

Inside the select you must have your `groupBy` column or generally as a rule whatever i inside select should be inside `groupBy`

Group by can accept multiple values so you can have something like this in your select:

```
select('serije_epizode','sezona','id_serije')
```

And in your group by you should have the same;

```
groupBy('serije_epizode','sezona','id_serije')
```

The 2nd and the "not so good practise" but have seen it in many projects  is inside your `database.php` file you are going to find your mysql setup.

In there you are going to find a field named `strict` which has a value `true`. If you change it to `false` and run `php artisan config:cache` your `group by` will work.

I would strongly suggest to go for the 1st option or even better create a model and use Eloquent but that's up to you.

Another option for you might be to use `distinct()` or `unique()` to return unique values from a column instead of `groupBy`

Comment: Thanks for this advice, but still it doesn't work. I'm getting error:
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'smf.serije_epizode.id_serije' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `id_serije`, `sezona`, `br_epizode` from `serije_epizode` where `id_serije` = 1 group by `sezona` order by `sezona` asc, `br_epizode` asc)

Comment: Judging by your error you did not use my answer. You still have 3 columns in select and 1 in group by.

Comment: When i add  id_serije in groupby, still getting same error.
Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'smf.serije_epizode.br_epizode' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `id_serije`, `sezona`, `br_epizode` from `serije_epizode` where `id_serije` = 1 group by `id_serije`, `sezona` order by `sezona` asc, `br_epizode` asc)

Comment: When i add all 3 field in GroupBY, then i have same results as without groupBy. I have tv show that is (id_serije / id_show), and then number season and number episode. I want to find tv show by id then all epizodes group by seasons. That is result that i cant find.

Comment: I have more than 1 solutions in my answer :) give a try to the next one if you cant have this work for you. I would leave the 2nd as last though.

Comment: When i activate strict to false, then i'm getting something better, but there is only one episode per season. I'm getting this.
https://i.imgur.com/lk0VbDf.png
It use only first episode in every season. Not all episodes. :(

Comment: But you group by season.That's expected. Are you sure you need this group by and not just an order by? Or maybe group by on another column?

Comment: Well that have logic. But what else can i do? What is my alernative? What is best way to do that thing with list of episodes  by seasons in some show? Getting season than do foreach and query in that foreach?

Comment: Then get all episodes in an array with multiple nested arrays inside and map it to specific array column 'sezona'. There any quite a few array functions in php to handle stuff like that

Answer (score 1):

You request for all columns and your columns are not processed (or calculated) then you have to add them into your group by clause.